# Requesting inputted data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which has a select input

```
<select class="form-control" id="taskSelect" name="taskSelect" >
    <option value="" name="task" id="task">Select One</option>
    <option value="1" name="task">1</option>
    <option value="2" name="task">2</option>
</select>
```

Now depending on what is selected, a sub form appears.  I have set up an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8f4fabnz/)

Now I need to pass any data that has been completed to a function

```
submitHandler: function(form){
    var params = $(form).serialize();
    generatePDF(params);
}
```

Normally to get the input I would do something like this

```
$('#someInput').val();
```

But in my situation I dont know what will be inputted so I am serializing things.  If selection 1 is selected, then I only need the inputs for the fields it displays, not the fields for selection 2.  Serializing seems to capture all inputs, not the ones that I want.

What is the best way to only pass the inputted data to the function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try splitting the form into 2 parts. Once this is done you can serialize only the selected form. This is assuming you don't have any other form elements outside the two tasks you mentioned above

Comment: Its actually quite a lot of elements, and because I am using JQuery Validate it is all in a single form for validation purposes

Comment: Probably you can use divs to selectively serialize all input elements within the div. Jquery allows you to serialize each input element separately. Use divs to group elements you want to serialize.